# For Auto Rig Pro is it better to have eyelids as separate object or as a mesh with eyeball object?

Tags: auto-rig-pro

I'm creating a cartoon style character with oval eyes and lattice.  I created two versions for eyelids.  One with the eyelid mesh included with the eyeball object, and another with the eyelid meshes as separate objects.  I like the look an simplicity of only one object, but which would be better suited for Auto Rig Pro 2.8 controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tough topic, and I've struggled with it mightily. I eventually found this video, which got results for me. But my problem was specifically getting the lattice deformers--whose purpose is to make the eyes oval shaped despite being rotated--to parent properly and to actually stay put during eye control manipulation. As to your specific question, I don't know if the video will provide a clear answer, but I know in standard ARP eye rigging practice, each eye is part of the same "object" during facial setup, and yet each eye works just fine later on when controlled independently by the rig. I expect this is because they each have their own independent vertex group, so that then the armature modifier can tell each eye which bone to follow. So based on this, I would imagine you could have your lids as part of the same eye object also, provided you give them separate vertex groups, and target some bone with them by giving those vertex groups the same name as that of the bone. Hope this helps.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1Di71uD578

Comment: By the way, I've started a new chat room here for Auto Rig Pro users. I'd like to eventually see whatever users of it there are on this site check it out and share their knowledge or experiences. Though I think there may be a minimum reputation score required to join. I hope I'm wrong about that.